# REST API Ajax simultaneously requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, rest

Is it wrong to make multiple ajax simultaneously requests to different endpoints of a REST API that end up modifying the same resource?

Note: each endpoint will modify different properties.

For example, let's assume that one endpoint modifies some properties for an order, like order_date and amount and another endpoint set's the link between the same order and a customer by changing the customer_id value from the orders table (I know that maybe this is not the best example, all these updates can be done with one endpoint).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally a requirements based question.  It is generally a bad idea to have a single resource be changed by multiple processes, but this ONLY matters if there is a consistency relationship between the data.  Consider some of the following questions:

If one or more of the AJAX calls fails does will that break your application?  If it will, then yes, this is a bad idea.  Will your application carry on regardless of what data you have at any given time?  If so, then no this doesn't matter.

Take some time to figure out what dependencies you have between your data calls and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing is not a shared resource even if it is stored in the same object because you are modifying different properties however take great care when using same object. if your requests to the server depends on the properties that are modified by the other request.

in general its not a good idea to use the same object to store data that is modified by more than one asynchronous function even if the properties are different. it makes your code confusing and harder to maintain since you have to manually coordinate your function calls to prevent race condition.

there are better ways to manage your asynchronous code using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea in **general**. But if your code is **small** and you can manage it then you can do it though its not **recommended**.

In the **long run**, it will cause you many problems **confusion**, **maintaining code**, **consistency** etc.

And if in any case another **developer** has to manage your code, It will be more **confusing** and **tough** for him.

In programming always keep things **flexible** and think in **long run**. Your requirements can **change in future** , what will you do then? write the whole program again? This is one thing , you also want to **avoid**.